# Trying to nest a lot of functions in excel

Tags: excel, nested

So I'll start by saying I have been searching and testing nesting formulas in excel to find a solution....but I can't do it anymore. Help is greatly appreciated. I'm working with excel 2013

I am working on a spreadsheet the has a column for employee's driver license "state". In the cell for each employee we are entering FL, TX, CA, etc. for their respective states.

What I would like to do is to automatically include a phrase pertaining to that particular state's renewal policy when the cell has FL, TX, CA entered.

For example. If I enter "FL" in the cell, I would like it to auto populate the cell with "FL can renew by mail". Or "TX valid for 90 days after leaving state". "CA valid for 45 days after leaving state". States without an out of state renewal policy will just have the two letters with no extra text.

I want to have the cells auto populate for all 50 states and their respective relicensing policy.

Thanks in advance

Comment: What have you tried so far? Have you looked into `VLOOKUP`?

Comment: Create a list of the state abbreviations in one column and the desired output in another then use VLOOKUP to return the correct description.

Comment: I have not tried vlookup. I've never used it, but I can tell it's probably exactly what I'm looking for. I'll give it a try tomorrow at work. I've had to learn everything in excel on the fly in the recent days as I've never used it before. Thanks for the input!